# How to use quotation and unquotation when calling tidyverse functions?

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, quosure

I don't understand how to use expressions and quotation/unquotation/quasiquotation in the context of the R tidyverse. In the following example, I thought that using the unquote (`!!`) operator would allow me to generate the required arguments for add_row after I evaluate expression `ex`. However, I get this error instead. I've read the [Metaprogramming Big Picture](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/meta-big-picture.html) and [Quasiquotation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) chapters in Advanced R, but I'm still having trouble understanding how to use these features correctly.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = 21:30)
df
#>     x  y  z
#> 1   1 11 21
#> 2   2 12 22
#> 3   3 13 23
#> 4   4 14 24
#> 5   5 15 25
#> 6   6 16 26
#> 7   7 17 27
#> 8   8 18 28
#> 9   9 19 29
#> 10 10 20 30
mini_df <- data.frame(x = 33:35, y = 43:45, z = 53:55)
mini_df
#>    x  y  z
#> 1 33 43 53
#> 2 34 44 54
#> 3 35 45 55

# store the expression I want to call in add_row
ex <- expr(paste0(names(df),':=',paste0('mini_df$',names(mini_df)),collapse=','))

# attempt to call add_row using arguments unquoted after evaluating expression ex
add_row(df,(!! eval(ex)), .after = 3L)
#> New rows in `add_row()` must use columns that already exist:
#> * Can't find column `"x:=mini_df$x,y:=mini_df$y,z:=mini_df$z"` in `.data`.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I should have been using unquote-splicing by calling `UQS()` or `!!!` instead. I didn't need to use the `eval()` or `expr()` functions at all. Instead, the proper usage was as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = 21:30)
mini_df <- data.frame(x = 33:35, y = 43:45, z = 53:55)
add_row(df,!!!mini_df, .after = 3L)
#>     x  y  z
#> 1   1 11 21
#> 2   2 12 22
#> 3   3 13 23
#> 4  33 43 53
#> 5  34 44 54
#> 6  35 45 55
#> 7   4 14 24
#> 8   5 15 25
#> 9   6 16 26
#> 10  7 17 27
#> 11  8 18 28
#> 12  9 19 29
#> 13 10 20 30
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For more on unquoting and unquote-splicing see:

[Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) - in particular, the line that states "A very useful feature of unquote-splicing is that the vector names become argument names"

[Quasiquotation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html)